# Why is our heliosphere an asymmetric croissant shape?

Tags: the-sun, solar-system, magnetic-field, solar-wind

The big, recent astronomy news about our [heliosphere's asymmetric croissant shape](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/uncovering-our-solar-system-s-shape) has me confused....

Some articles mention the influence on our solar system's outermost boundary of very hot cations, and since positive charges are affected differently by magnetic fields than negative ones, maybe this is the reason....

Or maybe we live in a weird part of the Galaxy?

Perhaps no one knows yet, and I'm getting too excited here.....

Answer (score 1):

> Why is our heliosphere an asymmetric croissant shape?

We don't actually know if this is correct.  It is one of several models proposed that predict the shape of the [heliosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere).  If the croissant shape is correct, it would likely be a general solution applicable to other astropheres, not just ours.